# Diamond inheritance with boost::bind

Tags: c++, boost-bind, diamond-problem

I have a design like this:

```
template <class T>
class A
{
};

template <class T>
class B : public A<T> 
{
};

template <class T>
class C : public A<T> 
{
};

template <class T>
class D : public C<T>, public B<T> 
{
};

struct TConcrete {
int xyz;
};

class Concrete : public D<TConcrete>
{
void Foo();
};

void
Concrete::Foo()
{
Bar (boost::bind(&A::Afunc, this, _1, _2), boost::bind(&C::Cfunc, this, _1, _2),     boost::bind(&D::Dfunc, this, _1, _2));
}
```

The compiler complains about the first boost::bind call. The call to function inside C and D have no issues. 
Here is the exact error:

boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp(384) : error C2594: 'newline' : ambiguous conversions from 'Concrete *' 
to 'A *'
        with
        [
        T=TConcrete
        ]

Any ideas what could be wrong with this?

Comment: At least one of those public inheritances should be `virtual public`.

Comment: Thanks. Need to start revising high school concepts. Got into c++ after a long time.

Comment: More often than not, using multiple inheritance for anything other than abstract classes (e.g. interfaces) is a sign that you may want to rethink your design.  It is very *rare* that multiple inheritance of non-abstract classes would be the best solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your inheritance diagram looks something like this:

```
           Concrete 
              |
              D
             / \
            C   B
           /     \
          A       A
```

When you try to convert your `Concrete*` into an `A*`, the compiler has no idea which instance of `A` you want. Do you want to convert to the `A` that `C` derives from, or the `A` that `B` derives from?

The solution is to use virtual inheritance to derive `B` and `C` from `A`, so that there is only one instance of `A`.

```
           Concrete 
              |
              D
             / \
            C   B
             \ /
              A
```